# connection string generated by atlas cluster using terraform not in correct format

Tags: express, terraform, amazon-ecs, mongodb-atlas, webpack.config.js

So im using terraform to create an atlas cluster but the output im getting is incompleteate to do my request terraform is givim me this:

mongodb+srv://esc-app-dbcluster-devel.b59mwv7.mongodb.net

and what i need shoul be more like this:

mongodb+srv://admin:admin@esc-app-dbcluster-devel.b59mwv7.mongodb.net/development?retryWrites=true&w=majority

or atleast thats the format that works with what im testing.

this is my terraform code:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    mongodbatlas = {
      source = "mongodb/mongodbatlas"
      version = "1.4.6"
    }
  }
}

provider "mongodbatlas" {
  public_key = var.atlas_public_key
  private_key = var.atlas_private_key
}

resource "mongodbatlas_cluster" "db-cluster" {
  project_id              = var.atlas_project_id
  name                    = var.db_cluster_name

  # Provider Settings "block"
  provider_name = "TENANT" //free tier
  backing_provider_name = "AWS"
  provider_region_name = "US_EAST_1" //free tier
  provider_instance_size_name = "M0" //free tier
}


resource "mongodbatlas_database_user" "dbuser" {
  username           = var.db_user
  password           = var.db_password
  project_id         = var.atlas_project_id
  auth_database_name = "admin"

  roles {
    role_name     = "readWrite"
    database_name = var.environment
  }

}

resource "mongodbatlas_project_ip_access_list" "test" {
  project_id = var.atlas_project_id
  cidr_block = var.cidr
}

output "db_cn_string" {
    value = mongodbatlas_cluster.db-cluster.connection_strings.0.standard_srv
}
```

code i use to connect

```
const environment = process.env.ENVIRONMENT;
const uridb = "mongodb+srv://admin:admin@esc-app-dbcluster-devel.b59mwv7.mongodb.net/development?retryWrites=true&w=majority" // working format 
//dburi = "mongodb+srv://esc-app-dbcluster-devel.b59mwv7.mongodb.net" --- format from terraform

console.log('environment:::::', environment);

let ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLES = {
  'process.env.ENVIRONMENT': JSON.stringify(environment),
  'process.env.PORT': JSON.stringify('80'),
  'process.env.MONGO_CONNECTION_STRING': JSON.stringify(uridb)
};
```

need a way  to genarate the proper connection string

Comment: Not sure if this will help but can you try: `mongodbatlas_cluster.db-cluster.connection_strings[0].standard_srv`? Also, if you were to dump the data for the entire object, would there be anything resembling the connection string you want? E.g., doing `mongodbatlas_cluster.db-cluster` in `terraform console`?

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example of how to insert user credentials into a connection string:

```
output "mongodbatlas_connection_string" {
  value     = replace(mongodbatlas_cluster.db-cluster.connection_strings[0].standard_srv, "/([\\w+]*).{3}(.*)/", "$1://${mongodbatlas_database_user.db_user.username}:${mongodbatlas_database_user.db_user.password}@$2")
  sensitive = true
}
```